# Pass variadic parameters further

Tags: c++, qt

I have a logging method called `trace`:

```
template <typename... Args>
void trace(const LogLevel ll, QString&& msg, Args... args)
{
     // operate on input data
}
```

Now I would like to create a wrapper function, with the same interface, that would call my `trace` function:

```
template <typename... Args>
void wrapper(const LogLevel ll, QString&& msg, Args... args)
{
     trace(ll, std::move(msg), args);
}
```

But this will not compile. I think I am not allowed to pass `args` this way. How can this functionality be accomplished?

Comment: "`args...`". But you should also read up on forwarding references and how they work, to avoid making needless copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expand the pack like

```
template <typename... Args>
void wrapper(const LogLevel ll, QString&& msg, Args... args)
{
     trace(ll, std::move(msg), args...);
}
```

Also note that you can use perfect forwarding as well so you don't cause copies.  That would look like

```
template <typename... Args>
void wrapper(const LogLevel ll, QString&& msg, Args&&... args)
{
     trace(ll, std::move(msg), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```