# Q_INVOKABLE variadic function

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In extension to this question: [Pass variadic parameters further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60619517/pass-variadic-parameters-further/60619592#60619592)

I am trying to make the `wrapper` method `Q_INVOKABLE static`:

```
template <typename... Args>
Q_INVOKABLE static void wrapper(const LogLevel ll, QString&& msg, Args&&... args)
{
    CLogger::instance().trace(ll, std::move(msg), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

But MOC will not compile this code: `error: C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Args'`
Is there any way for accomplishing variadic functions being esported to the QML part?

Comment: AFAIK `Q_INVOKABLE ` can't be applied on templates. It could be applied on instantiation of template. Note there is no mechanism which would allow QML to instantiate a C++ template.

Comment: As a workaround... you could define a function with a bunch of default parameters.  Yes it is not the same.

Comment: Any suggestions on a QML based logging function then maybe...?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler will do that and no changes in QML code but using standard https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html logging. That is what we do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on @RossRogers comment, I created the following method:

header:

```
Q_INVOKABLE static void log(LogLevel l,
                            QString m,
                            QVariant v1 = QVariant(),
                            QVariant v2 = QVariant(),
                            QVariant v3 = QVariant());
```

source:

```
 * @brief   A QML enabled wrapper function for the logger trace method. It
 *          allows to use the trace (printf style) in QML with up to 3
 *          parsable arguments.
 * @param   l: trace log level.
 * @param   m: message to be printed.
 * @param   v1: oprional parsable param 1.
 * @param   v2: oprional parsable param 2.
 * @param   v3: oprional parsable param 3.
 */
void CSystem::log(LogLevel l, QString m, QVariant v1, QVariant v2, QVariant v3)
{
    CLogger::instance().trace(l, std::move(m),
            std::move(v1), std::move(v2), std::move(v3));
}
```

It is a very dirty, and most likelly now very efficient workaround that allows for parsing up to 3 values. Inside the `trace` method I ommit the invalid `QVariant` objects.